# 'Model' does not contain a definition for 'Object"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to print out data from an SQL query, but I'm running into error after error.

Bassically what Im trying to do is fetch some data from teachers out of a database, and then make a list of them on my view. However everytime I try to print, I get this error

> ViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'FirstName' and no
>   extension method 'FirstName' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ViewModel' could be found.

Here's my code;

**ViewModel**

```
namespace Ability.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public virtual IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
        public Skill Skill { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string campus = Request.Params["Campus"];

            if (campus != null)
            {
                if (campus == "Alle")
                {
                    var teachers = (from t in db.Teachers
                                    select t);
                }
                else
                {
                    var teachers = (from t in db.Teachers
                                    where t.Campus == campus
                                    select t );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var teachers = (from t in db.Teachers
                                select t);
            }

            var Model = new ViewModel
            {
                Teachers = db.Teachers.ToList(),
            };

            return View(Model);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Ability.Models.ViewModel>

<h2>Teachers at Thomas More</h2>


               ...


@foreach (var Teacher in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Teacher.FirstName
            </td>
            <td>
                @Teacher.LastName
            </td>
            <td>
                @Teacher.Email
            </td>
            <td>
                @Teacher.Campus
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I'm not sure if it mathers, but I already tried doing several things including changing my loop to

```
@foreach (var Teacher in Model.Teachers)
```

but then I receive a similar error

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Teachers'
>   and no extension method 'Teachers' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IEnumerable' could be found

Looking forward to any help I can receive!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of things that doesn't make sense.

First of all, where do you use the `teachers`?

Personally, I think that the following code is more reasonable:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    IEnumerable<Teacher> teachers = Enumerable.Empty<Teacher>();

    string campus = Request.Params["Campus"];
    if (campus != null)
    {
        if (campus == "Alle")
        {
            teachers = (from t in db.Teachers
                        select t);
        }
        else
        {
            teachers = (from t in db.Teachers
                        where t.Campus == campus
                        select t );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        teachers = (from t in db.Teachers
                    select t);
    }

    var Model = new ViewModel
    {
        Teachers = teachers
    };

    return View(Model);
}
```

Second, you have to initialize also the other properties of `ViewModel` in the above action method.

Now let's go to the view. You pass there a model of type `ViewModel`. When you want to iterate through the teachers sequence, you can try this:

```
@foreach (var teacher in Model.Teachers)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @teacher.FirstName
        </td>
        <td>
            @teacher.LastName
        </td>
        <td>
            @teacher.Email
        </td>
        <td>
            @teacher.Campus
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

All the above makes sense **provided that** `db.Teachers` is an `IEnumerable<Teacher>`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I changed my code like you suggested. However I still get the red underline with the error " 'IEnumerable<ViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Teachers' and no extension method 'Teachers' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found "

Comment: nvm, problem solved, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @NicolasDecroos You are welcome. I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 3):

You're sending the type `ViewModel` to the view:

```
var Model = new ViewModel
{
    Teachers = db.Teachers.ToList(),
};

return View(Model);
```

But it's *expecting* the type `IEnumerable<Ability.Models.ViewModel>`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Ability.Models.ViewModel>
```

That is, it's expecting a *collection* where you're providing an *object*.

Given the usage in the view, it seems like you should just change it to expect a single object:

```
@model Ability.Models.ViewModel
```

This would allow you to directly access the property you're looking for:

```
@foreach (var Teacher in Model.Teachers)
```

---

**Side Note:** The logic in your controller doesn't look correct.  You conditionally create a `teachers` variable, but then never use it.  Instead, you just materialize *all* of the teachers in the database and send them *all* to the view.  If you intend to see all of the teachers, you can remove most of that code.  If you intend to see specific teachers, you would want to use the variable you created.  Reference [@Christos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34568660/328193) for a practical example of that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I've tried your solution, but it still give me the error "'IEnumerable<ViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Teachers' and no extension method 'Teachers' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found" . Sorry if this is an obvious mistake, really new to this.

Comment: @NicolasDecroos: It sounds like you didn't successfully change the model type declaration on the top line of the view.  Can you confirm?

Comment: this is the line [AT]model Ability.Models.ViewModel

Comment: @NicolasDecroos: Interesting.  Which specific line of code throws that error?

Comment: Sorry, I just copied your line exactly, and now it works. Must have been a small typo. Thank you very much for all your help

Comment: @NicolasDecroos: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Your model is a list of ViewModels. You needed to use `@foreach (var Teacher in Model.Teachers)`.